# Таймер в функции не работает

Tags: python

Есть вот такой код:

```
import time

def Timer():
    sec = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        sec += 1
        return sec

while True: print(Timer())
```

И этот код каждую секунду выводит единицу, хотя по идее должен выводить числа по порядку. Почему не работает? Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему!

Comment: Функция `Timer` просто создаёт локальную переменную с числом 0, меняет её значение на 1 и завершает свою работу. Если вызвать её ещё раз, повторится всё то же самое и снова получится число 1. В этом коде нет ничего, что могло бы делать «числа по порядку»

Comment: Как предлагаете решить проблему?

Comment: А какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Зачем вам вообще функция, что мешает написать цикл без функции?

Comment: Мне необходима многопоточность для дальнейшей реализации программы, для реализации многопоточности просто необходимо иметь цикл внутри функции

Comment: Ну тогда просто замените return на print, наверное?

Comment: @АндрейКоваленко тогда замените в функции return на print, а снаружи функцию один раз запускайте в потоке через threading.

Comment: при каждом вызове функции sec сначала 0, потом 1, на этом выполнение функции заканчивается. При следующем вызове функции sec опять 0, потом 1, после чего выполнение функции опять заканчивается. Идея, по которой код должен выводить числа по порядку, неверна, потому что число каждый раз сбрасывается на 0.

Comment: и опять видим заголовок, который вообще никак не связан с проблемой в самом вопросе. Во-первых, тут нет никакого таймера. Во-вторых, все работает.